# Need to delete ns1: from soap call to the server

Tags: php, xml, soap

I use SOAP as a method to communicate with the asp.net service. The problem is that I need to pass the XML without `ns1:` .
This is the request I send now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ex.ex.com/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetInfoFromSending>
<ns1:Key>XXX</ns1:Key>
<ns1:ObjectID>2468</ns1:ObjectID>
</ns1:GetInfoFromSending>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But the format of the request needed is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetInfoFromSendingList xmlns="http://ex.ex.com/">
      <Key>string</Key>
      <ObjectID>int</ObjectID>
    </GetInfoFromSendingList>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried using [MSSoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php#74123)  from PHP Manual but doesn't seem to work

```
try {
    $soap = new MSSoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    var_dump($soap);
    $data = $soap->__soapCall('GetInfoFromSending', array('parameters'=>$params));
    var_dump($soap);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

What is `$namespace = "http://tempuri.com";` in [MSSoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php#74123)

Comment: Have you tried nusoap instead of MSSoapClient?

Comment: No what is that :)) ? @ Alireza Mirzaeiyan

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by using the default `__soapCall` from SOAP.